# Virtual assignment operator not allowing static_cast

Tags: c++, polymorphism, assignment-operator

I have the following MWE code:

```
#include <algorithm>

class Base{
public:
    int baseMember;
    friend void swap(Base& in, Base& out)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(in.baseMember, out.baseMember);
    }
    virtual Base& operator=(Base obj)
    {
        swap(*this, obj);
        return *this;
    }
    Base() : baseMember(1)
    {       
    }
};
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    int derivedMember;
    friend void swap(Derived& in, Derived& out)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(in.derivedMember, out.derivedMember);
        swap(static_cast<Base&>(in), static_cast<Base&>(out));
    }
    virtual Base& operator=(Base obj)
    {
        swap(*this, static_cast<Derived&>(obj));
        return *this;
    }
    Derived() : Base(), derivedMember(2)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base *b1 = new Derived();
    Base *b2 = new Derived();
    *b1 = *b2;
    delete b1;
    delete b2;
}
```

I have two `Base` pointers pointing to `Derived` data. I then do an assignment of the contents of the pointers. Since the `Base` class' assignment operator is `virtual`, polymorphism kicks in and the assignment operator of the `Derived` class (with the same signature) is called instead.

However, the `static_cast` to transform the source into a `Derived` object fails. Or, well, it successfully transforms it into a `Derived` object, but its `derivedMember` is garbage (after being initially set in the constructor).

How can this be avoided? How can an assignment between the `Derived` contents of two `Base` pointers be done?

Comment: Use `dynamic_cast` instead, it's safer because it checks if reference is *really* refers to `Derived` object.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has a typo and inherently unsafe behavior. The typo is here:

```
virtual Base& operator=(Base obj) // <-- should be base&
{
    swap(*this, static_cast<Derived&>(obj));
    return *this;
}
```

If you fix this, your code should work **in the simple example provided**. But it would still fail at large, because how would you guarantee the argument passed to `operator=` will be in fact of `Derived` type?

Answer (score 1):

Passing an argument by value slices that argument.  So by the time your `operator=` function is called, you have an actual `Base`, not a `Derived`.

I'm afraid you'll need to overload your assignment for lvalues and rvalues.

```
virtual Base& operator=(const Base&);
virtual Base& operator=(Base&&);
```

Comment: Ah. Of course. I was trying to use the copy-swap idiom and make use of the copy-constructor, but of course that'll only create a copy of `Base`. However, does this mean copy-swap doesn't work in such a case? I can't use `swap()` on a constant reference or on an rvalue.

Comment: Or should I use the const reference to create a temporary object and use that in the `swap`, as what the [SO C++ FAQ on copy-swap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/2175231) calls a "naive implementation of the idiom"?